# Azure C# App Service ODBC connection to Redshift

Tags: c#, azure, odbc, amazon-redshift

I have developed an Azure Api Service (Rest API) that needs to connect occasionally to a aws Redshift database.  This is working fine on my development environment (once I installed the Redshift ODBC driver, and created an DSN entry) however fails on Azure when I publish.

I am assuming it is because I have to install the RS driver manually and configure the DSN but at a loss on how to do this.

Any guidance would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using [Azure Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/). As [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) states as follows:

> All Azure Web Apps (as well as Mobile App/Services, WebJobs and Functions) **run in a secure environment called a sandbox**. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available.

For [Install and Configure the Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver on Microsoft Windows Operating Systems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/install-odbc-driver-windows.html), you need to have the administrator privileges of your server and install the ODBC driver in your server, but Sandbox has some limitations, you could not install ODBC driver in your Azure Web App. You may need to migrate your Api Service to Azure Cloud Services or Azure VM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bruce and you are right.  I have since migrated this solution to be a loud Service.  One side effect seems to be that now in debug the emulator cannot see the driver on my development system - is this expected, and if so, I am going to raise another question on how if possible, I can install the driver to the emulated instance

Comment: For the Azure Cloud Service approach, you could RDP to your cloud instance and manually install the ODBC driver and create an DSN entry, but at this time, your installations would not be persistent, if your cloud role instance restarts, then the installation would miss. Moreover, you could leverage the [Start-up Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-startup-tasks) to install the component before your cloud role instance starts.

Comment: I do not check the Azure Cloud Service approach on my side, so you could raise another question with more details. I used to just leverage the Azure VM and install the component through RDP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and you are indeed right.  I did get tripped up as you need to install the x64 redshift driver on the VM but now all working correctly.  Thanks